# Pandas: Creating empty dataframe in for loop, appending

Tags: pandas, loops

I would like to create a ((25520*43),3) pandas Dataframe in a for loop.

I created the dataframe like:

```
lst=['Region', 'GeneID', 'DistanceValue']

df=pd.DataFrame(index=lst).T
```

And now I want to fill 'Region', 43 times with 25520 values. Also GeneID and DistanceValue.

This is my for loop for that:

```
for i in range(43):
    df.DistanceValue = np.sort(distance[i,:])
    df.Region = np.ones(25520) * i
    args = np.argsort(distance[i,:])
    df.GeneID = ids[int(args[i])]
```

But than my df exists just of (25520, 3). So I just have the last iteration for 43 filled in.
How can I concat all iteration one to 43 in my df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your example but there are couple of corrections you can make:

```
lst=['Region', 'GeneID', 'DistanceValue']
df=pd.DataFrame(index=lst).T

region = []
for i in range(43):
    region.append(np.ones(25520))

flat_list = [item for sublist in region for item in sublist]
df.Region = flat_list
```

First create a new list outside loop and then append values within loop in this list.
The `flat_list` will consolidate all `43` lists to one and then you can map it to the `DataFrame`. It is always easier to fill `DataFrame` values outside of loop.

Similarly you can update all 3 columns.